# Iphone: how to play a directory containing MP3 from OneDrive?

Tags: iphone, mp3

I don't use iTunes, I just use plain MP3 stored in directories, I also have FLAC files. I stored them on OneDrive and use the OneDrive application from the APP. I use the application to download them on my phone *"Make the file available offline"*.

The OneDrive application sucks and only allow *to play 1 file*, there is no queue, no playlist, nothing. I am looking for a **solution to read a directory of audio files on iPhone**.

Comment: While I appreciate your pioneering spirit in seeking out alternative ways to play music, sometimes the best way is the easiest and built-in way that the phone was designed for: iTunes. There are other media players (VLC springs to mind) that might work for you, especially if you are wedded to FLAC, and they are just a search away in the app store.

Comment: *The OneDrive application sucks and only allow to play 1 file, there is no queue, no playlist, nothing.*  OneDrive is **not** a music player app so expecting it to have these features is not realistic.  Get an actual music player app if you want to play music.

Comment: I am not so sure about this statement in the case of iPhone. The files downloaded from the OneDrive APP are not available from the other applications of the iPhone. You basically need to duplicate the files outside the OneDrive APP so that other players can read them. This is why it's pretty annoying. VLC, I just tested it, can directly access the files from OneDrive using cloud services (Web API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC allows to connect to various cloud services including OneDrive and can play MP3. You can download it from the App Store.